# Empty all the rows in Orient-DB

Tags: database, orientdb

Is there are a command to flush/empty all the classes/clusters in Orient-DB.

Like Empty function in MySQL.

P.S : Searched here as well : https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Console-Commands

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such command available.

If you want to preserve the meta data of the classes, you can use the `truncate` command (same as most RDBMS). It deletes all records from all clusters of the specified class (but keeps the meta data about the class):

```
truncate class <yourclass>
```

If you want to truncate all **custom** classes (so excluding the OrientDB classes, which all start with capital "O"), you can use this script:

```
  connect plocal:<yoururl> <yourusername> <yourpassword>;
  js var result = db.query('select name from (select expand(classes) from metadata:schema) where name.charAt(0) <> "O"'); 
  for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { 
    var className = result[i].getRecord().field('name'); 
    db.command('truncate class ' + className);
  }; 
  result.length + ' classes truncated'; 
  end;
  exit
```

Save this script as `truncate-all.osql`.
To execute this script, go to `ORIENTDB_HOME/bin` directory and execute:

```
$ ./console.sh truncate-all.osql
```

Comment: Oops. Sorry. 
I got confused. Thought Drop & Truncate sql statement meant the same(to remove the table). 

One more question, does truncating cluster, removes the edges ?

Comment: Vertices and Edges are just specialized classes used in the Graph context. So yes, truncate will remove all classes, including Vertices and Edges. I have edited your question, removing the MySQL mention (not relevant / incorrect)