# Clear OrientDB database

Tags: java, orientdb, nosql

Given a `com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabase<T>` object, what's the best programmatical way (no sql, no console script) to clear the database (that's erase each and every object but respect the existing schema)?

Comment: You can look this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134059/empty-all-the-rows-in-orient-db. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Alessandro's comment and rmuller's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134059/empty-all-the-rows-in-orient-db), I've built a java helper method.

```
db.getMetadata().getSchema().getClasses().stream()
     .filter(oClass -> !oClass.getName().startsWith(ORIENTDB_CLASS_PREFIX)) //
     .forEach(oClass -> {
          try {
              oClass.truncate();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              LOGGER.warn("Not possible to truncate class " + oClass.getName(), e);
          }
     });
```

Comment: what is ORIENTDB_CLASS_PREFIX?

Comment: private static final String ORIENTDB_CLASS_PREFIX = "O";

Comment: In case of graph ..its not working.Please help